# Node.js/Express POST data not sending

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason I am not able to send/receive POST data. I am trying to simply console.log the post data in the /save route Am I missing something?

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    div#startbutton
        p start
    div#endbutton
        p stop
    div#resetbutton
        p reset
    div#savebutton
        p save
    div#container
        form(name='textform', method='post', action='/save')
            input(type="submit", value="Submit")
            textarea#thetextarea(rows=20 cols=30)
```

route:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Recorder Prototype' });
});

router.post('/save', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.thetextarea);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("=============================");
    res.render('data', { title: 'Save', textstring: req.body.thetextarea });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form controls have no `name` attributes. Without names, they cannot be successful and won't be included in the submitted data.

(Your form itself does have a `name` attribute, but that is legacy markup and you should use `id` instead. Only form controls (like `input` and `textarea`) should have `name`s)